# ORA-01722 Error when running stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a stored procedure however when I run it with an a valid Number it gives me an ORA-01722 error. I checked to make sure that the columns in the where clause where the parameter is used is of NUMBER type. I checked to make sure that the record exists. Note: When I take out c.charges-c.payment the query runs fine.

```
create procedure patient_InfoNew(vpatientID NUMBER) IS
  x VARCHAR2(300);
BEGIN
  select a.firstname ||
         a.lastname || ' ' ||
         a.ssn || ' ' ||
         a.streetname || ' ' ||
         a.phonenumber || ' ' ||
         b.servicedate || ' ' ||
         b.servicetype || ' ' ||
         c.charges - c.payment || ' ' ||
         e.name || ' ' ||
         e.insnumber into x
    from patient a,
         patientaccount b,
         patient_info c,
         patientinsurance d,
         insurance e
    where a.id = vpatientID AND
          e.id = d.insuranceid AND
          a.id = b.id AND
          a.id = c.id AND
          a.id = d.id AND
          b.servicedate = (Select MAX(servicedate)
                             from patientaccount
                             where id = vpatientID);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN                 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error ' || SQLCODE || SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,80));  
  WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Divide by zero');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No such record was found');
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error ' || SQLCODE || SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,80));
END;
```

This is the error I get below:

```
No such record was found 
Error -1722ORA-01722: invalid number 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Well, what are the values for c.charges and c.payment?  What is their data type in the table?

Comment: @OldProgrammer For the case I am testing they both have a value of 250  and both are NUMBER types.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of all the tables involved in this query. Also of interest are the values in PATIENT_INFO.ID. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your subtraction in parentheses: `(c.charges - c.payment)`

If you don't do that, you're essentially trying to subtract strings (everything on the left side of the minus is concatenated together, minus everything on the right side concatenated together).

Neither side evaluates to a valid number.

More information on the order of operations is here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/02_funds.htm

Notice that subtraction and concatenation are at the same level, so you need parentheses to clarify the meaning of your expression.